# Expected value of the sign of a normal random variable

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expectation

Let $x\in\Bbb{R}$ be a normal random variable with mean $\bar{x}$ and variance $\sigma_x^2$. I'm curious about a new variable that is defined as the sign of $s$, say $s=\operatorname{sgn}(x)\in\{\pm1\}$. What is the expected value of this variable?
Based on the answers below,
$$
\Bbb{E}[s]
=
(-1)\cdot P(x<0) + 1\cdot P(x>0)
=
-P\left(\frac{x-\bar{x}}{\sigma_x}<-\frac{\bar{x}}{\sigma_x}\right)
+
P\left(\frac{x-\bar{x}}{\sigma_x}>-\frac{\bar{x}}{\sigma_x}\right)
\implies
\Bbb{E}[s]
=
-P\left(z < -\frac{\bar{x}}{\sigma_x}\right)
+
P\left(z > -\frac{\bar{x}}{\sigma_x}\right),
$$
where $z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ is the standard normal variable. Thus,
$$
\Bbb{E}[s]
=
-\Phi\left(-\frac{\bar{x}}{\sigma_x}\right)
+
1 - \Phi\left(-\frac{\bar{x}}{\sigma_x}\right)
=
1 - 2\Phi\left(-\frac{\bar{x}}{\sigma_x}\right),
$$
where $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal variable. Thus,
$$
\Bbb{E}[s]
=
\operatorname{erf}
\left(
\frac{\bar{x}}{\sqrt{2}\sigma_x}
\right).
$$

Comment: Observe that your expectation can only take nonnegative values. The third equality is wrong.

Comment: I see, thank you. I'll get it done and return to update the question.

Comment: $\sqrt2$ must dissappear everywhere except in the last equality where function [$\text{erf}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) comes in. Also $\Phi$ is a Cumulative *Distribution* Function (CDF). Not a cumulative "density" as you call it.

Comment: @drhab thanks! $\sqrt{2}$ was due to copy-paste.. I'll correct it. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\mathsf {E(sgn}(X))=1\cdot\mathsf P(X>0)+(-1)\cdot\mathsf P(X<0)$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have update the question accordingly. May you take a quick look? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check your last equation… it's wrong… ofc the symmetry of the density depends on $\overline{s}$ and additionally if we assume $\overline{s} = 0$ we would get $$\int_{-\infty}^{0}(-1)f(s)\mathrm{d}s = - \int_{0}
 ^\infty f(s)\mathrm{d}s$$